# Why can I not deserialize "Wed Mar 09 14:02:57 +0800 2022" with format "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"?

Tags: java, jackson, datetime-parsing

Why can't I use `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy` to deserialize `Wed Mar 09 14:02:57 +0800 2022`? Is there anything wrong?

I am using Jackson and I added this annotation in my entity class

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy")
private Date created_at;
```

However, I got this error:

> Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "Wed Mar
> 09 14:02:57 +0800 2022": expected format "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.util.Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` or another class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I can get both `DateTimeFormatter`/`ZonedDateTime` and `SimpleDateFormat` can parse the value you've provided.  I'd suspect that issue has something to do with "how" you're parsing the text

Comment: Could it be a locale problem? `Wed` and `Mar` are in English, so if your library expects a different language, it would explain. What is the default locale of your JVM? What happens if you change it to an English-speaking locale?

Comment: As shown in the duplicate, add `locale="en"` to the annotation.

Comment: I changed the locale to English then it works, so thank you, everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to escape from that format and use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) instead.

Also, it's better to use the classes in the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: Those are two good pieces of advice.